# Is this way of solving a line integral on a vector field correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Given $\nabla\varphi = \mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{r}(t)$ from $a$ to $b$,

$$\int_c\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = \int_c\nabla\varphi\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} = \int_a^b\nabla\varphi(\mathbf{r})\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}~\mathrm{d}t = \int_a^b\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(\varphi(\mathbf{r}))~\mathrm{d}t = \varphi(\mathbf{r}(b))-\varphi(\mathbf{r}(a)).$$

Comment: I think it is fine. The first condition says the field $\;F\;$ has a potential $\;\phi\;$ and then the integral only depends on ends points of the integration path.

Comment: Yes, given that the curl of $F$ is zero (and that is the case since it can be written as the gradient of a scalar field!)